# List Validation Settings: Ignore case when finding word

Tags: validation

I am validating a column to see if it contains blacklisted words. I want to capture the words whether they are upper case or lower case but I cannot seemed to find any solution on the internet. Does anyone know the proper syntax to ignore case? Or if I can compare the words by converting it to lower case first?

I have the following as my validation formula:

```
=AND(IF(ISERROR(FIND("blacklistword",Title)),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("blacklistwordtwo",Title)),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("blacklistwordthree",Title)),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("blacklistwordfour",Title)),TRUE))
```

Your help is much appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer.

> =AND(IF(ISERROR(FIND("kns",LOWER([Title]))),TRUE),
>   IF(ISERROR(FIND("lj",LOWER([Title]))),TRUE),
>   IF(ISERROR(FIND("wah lau",LOWER([Title]))),TRUE),
>   IF(ISERROR(FIND("lao jiao",LOWER([Title]))),TRUE))

This website shows all the synthax: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071%28v=office.14%29.aspx).